# Can I get at my application code from inside a Selenium test?

Tags: wordpress, unit-testing, selenium

I'm writing unit and integration tests for a WordPress site, using PHPUnit and Selenium. There's a useful WP test library for PHPUnit, used by extending a special WP_UnitTestCase instead of PHPUnit_TestCase.

So far so good. What would be truly useful, though, would be if my Selenium tests could also execute code in the context of WordPress. So for example, I could build and manipulate users, posts etc while testing client-side behaviour, much in the way you can do with a Rails integration test.

Is there any way I can use the features of a WP_UnitTestCase in the context of a Selenium test?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with WP_UnitTestCase but you could look at this lightweight tool I developed which creates a test WordPress instance.

https://github.com/evomase/phpunit-wordpress

You should be able to integrate it with Selenium easily as you would do with a standalone application. The only difference will be that in `build.php`, you will need to change the `WP_SITEURL` to the VirtualHost you've created for your test instance.

Comment: Thanks, this looks splendid - will check it out. There's a good post about WP_UnitTestCase here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9138215/unit-testing-wordpress-plugins